# How to calculate between two timings SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table 1:

| ID | Name | Class | Date | Intime | Outtime | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Paul | 1st | 09-12-2022 | 8:30 AM | 4:30 PM | 8 |

Could someone help me how can I calculate `Intime`, `Outtime` between hours. Thank you...

Comment: @ahmed, Thank you for responding Intime and outtime datatypes are "Time(7)"

Comment: Try with `DateDiff(Hour, Intime, Outtime)`